# How to consume Twitter Streaming API using Heroku and MongoLab?

Tags: api, mongodb, twitter, heroku, mlab

I'm looking to use the Twitter Streaming API to scrape all tweets for a few keywords and store them in a database. I would rather not run the workflow locally so I had been looking at ways to use the API with Heroku and MongoLab.

I found this example (using ruby) which got me very close to what I was trying to do:
http://www.jefflinwood.com/2011/08/deploying-tweeter-keeper-on-the-heroku-cedar-stack/
http://github.com/joslynesser/mongo-twitter-streaming

Unfortunately the example stopped working for me. It seems that support for the twitter gem I was using was dropped. I tried going back and installing everything from step one again, however, when I tried pushing the files to Heroku I keep getting the msg:
"Could not find twitter-1.6.0 in any of the sources"

I've updated the Gemfile to reference the latest version of each of the twitter related gems and ran bundle update as well. I can't seem to find any other dependencies for twitter-1.6.0, but still get that msg.

I'm having difficulty finding other similar examples online to work from, but this seems like a common enough thing to be doing. Any help would be appreciated, either in troubleshooting the issue above or with leads on other code that I could work from.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using the Ruby module ['tweetstream'](https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream) to connect to the streaming API, it has good documentation and supports the newer v1.1 OAuth connection protocol.

I have [some code](https://github.com/jhrrsn/tw_rb/blob/master/stream.rb) (GitHub) that uses it to parse and write tweets to a local MongoDB instance, if that helps.